# QPX. How many returns per query?

Tags: python, json, r, api, web-scraping

I'm looking to use this API for Google Flights to gather some flight data for project I hope to complete. I have one question tho. Can anyone see a way to request multiple dates for the same route in just one call? Or does it have to multiple requests?
Thanks so much I have seen it suggested that it is possible but haven't found any evidence:)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add more than one flight to the request, see the google developer tutorial for qpx. I am not sure though how many flights fit in one request.